# Set Global Variables Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, global-variables

I have recently decided to adopted Codeigniter as a PHP framework.

I would like to set some variables that should be available to all my controllers/models/views.

How would I go about this?

Comment: You probably shouldn't. You could make them class-level constants in your models though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [CodeIgniter's documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/loader.html) on `$this->load->vars()`.

The documentation states:

> This function takes an associative array as input and generates
>   variables using the PHP extract function. This function produces the
>   same result as using the second parameter of the `$this->load->view()`
>   function. The reason you might want to use this function
>   independently is if you would like to set some global variables in the
>   constructor of your controller and have them become available in any
>   view file loaded from any function. You can have multiple calls to
>   this function. The data get cached and merged into one array for
>   conversion to variables.